# storing and accessing implementation specific data of a class from generic type of its interface in c#

Tags: c#, generics, stackexchange.redis

I'm trying to write a generic cache repository that adds a base key to each data type that is being cached.

```
    public interface ICacheModel
    {
        private static readonly string _baseKey;
        public static string GetBaseCacheKey()
        {
            return _baseKey;
        }
    }
    public interface ICacheRepository<T> where T : class, ICacheModel
    {
        Task<T> GetAsync(string key);
    }
    public class CacheRepository<T> : ICacheRepository<T> where T : class, ICacheModel
    {
        private readonly IDistributedCache _distributedCache;

        public CacheRepository(IDistributedCache distributedCache)
        {
            _distributedCache = distributedCache;
        }

        public async Task<T> GetAsync(string key)
        {
            var res = await _distributedCache.GetAsync<T>(T.GetBaseCacheKey() + key );
            return res;
        }
    }
```

I then inherit any object that I plan to cache from ICacheModel and Inject the ICacheRepository anywhere I need to do caching in my project.

but I can't access the static method `GetBaseCacheKey()` due to compliler error CS0119

Any idea on how I can have this functionality?

Update:

```
    public class CacheSampleClass : ICacheModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }

        private static readonly string _baseKey = "CacheSampleClass-";
        public static string GetBaseCacheKey()
        {
            return _baseKey;
        }
    }
```

this is an example of the inherited classes that I want to cache.
I want the GetBaseCacheKey to be unique among all objects that are made from the CacheSampleClass and diffrent from all objects that are made from some other class that inherits ICacheModel

Comment: `ICacheModel.GetBaseCacheKey()`.

Comment: this removes the compiler error but doesn't work when called on a repository of a type like this: ```
    public class CacheSampleObject : ICacheModel
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Prop1 { get; set; }
        public string Prop2 { get; set; }

        private static readonly string _baseKey = "CacheSampleObject-";
        public static string GetBaseCacheKey()
        {
            return _baseKey;
        }
    }```

Comment: You can't implement a static method like that; they belong to their declaring type only. Why not declare it as a instance method when each implementing class needs their own version?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay because I need to access that method from ICacheRepository<T>

Comment: Access it using ICacheModel.GetBaseCacheKey(). If your argument then is that "then it's not per T", then you're right, but it's not. You don't inherit the static stuff. There is only one declaration here, it's the one in ICacheModel. Each type implementing this interface does not get its own copy of those static members.

Comment: I was hoping that there was a type similar to static that was suitable for this situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't implement a static interface method; static members belong to their declaring type only.

You could do something like this instead:

```
public interface ICacheModelKeyProvider<T> where T : class
{
    string BaseKey { get; }
}
```

Then in your repository:

```
public class CacheRepository<T> : ICacheRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IDistributedCache distributedCache;
    private readonly ICacheModelKeyProvider<T> keyProvider;

    public CacheRepository(
        IDistributedCache distributedCache,
        ICacheModelKeyProvider<T> keyProvider)
    {
        this.distributedCache = distributedCache;
        this.keyProvider = keyProvider;
    }

    public async Task<T> GetAsync(string key)
    {
        var res = await _distributedCache.GetAsync<T>(keyProvider.BaseKey + key);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Then each model type you create would need a `ICacheModelKeyProvider` before it could have a repository.

e.g.

```
public class CacheSampleClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

public class CacheSampleClassKeyProvider : ICacheModelKeyProvider<CacheSampleClass>
{
    public string BaseKey { get; } = "CacheSampleClass-"; 
}
```

Or if you want default behaviour you could even have a generic provider:

```
public class DefaultKeyProvider<T> : ICacheModelKeyProvider<T>
{
    public string BaseKey { get; } = $"{typeof(T).Name}-"; 
}
```

And you could even nest that class if it feels neater:

```
public class CacheSampleClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public class KeyProvider : DefaultKeyProvider<CacheSampleClass> { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would probably be to just use reflection to get the class name as the "baseCacheKey".

```
_distributedCache.GetAsync<T>(typeof(T).FullName  + key );
```

Another solution would be to define the base-key as a parameter for your cache object rather than for the type:

```
public CacheRepository(IDistributedCache distributedCache, string baseKey) 
...
```

Third solution would be to define a property in the interface:

```
public interface ICacheModel
{
        public string BaseKey {get;}
}
```

The implementation of said interface could just provide a implementation of the get method that returns a constant or literal value, so there does not to be any per-object field for this. But the property cannot be static as in the posted example.

Each alternative have some advantages and dissadvantages, so it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: thanks for the reply. the closest one to what I had in mind is the third solution. but I want that property to be unique among all objects that are made from the same class that inherits the ICacheModel

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot guarantee that except by just following due diligence yourself when implementing those types. Would it be OK to just use the full type name of the implementing type as the key?

Comment: I could solve it that way but it wouldn't add anything to my c# experience

Answer (score 1):

Static members in interfaces were introduced in C# 8.0 and I suggest you to avoid using them because interfaces usually should disconnect implementation(field) from contract(method or property).

In your case, its better to convert to regular property

```
public interface ICacheModel
{
   string GetBaseCacheKey();
}
```

and move implementation that uses static field to class that implements your interface

Comment: thanks for the reply but how am I supposed to access that from the  ICacheRepository<T>?

Comment: You can't, what you want is not supported directly.